# R fixed length array of empty arrays

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array, vector, dataframe

I know this has been asked a bunch previously but I was having trouble making sense of what I found.  I am looking to create a fixed length array of array of doubles in R, what would be the correct declaration for this?  I think want to be able to push elements into these arrays, something like `array[1][]=0.1` , `array[2][]=0.2`, etc.

Comment: How is this different than a two row matrix with N columns? Defining a length N list and populating it with two element vectors is also easy.

Comment: I am pushing elements inside a loop so it will end up being N arrays of different lengths.

Comment: Then it's just a list. Where's the complication?

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct data structure and its declaration would be.  Would it be a list of vectors of type double or a vector of vectors?

Comment: In R a list is not typed. You could make a class for which there are specific methods. It's still not clear what is meant by the empty pair of '[]' at the end of this call. It's better to describe desired results in natural language than in some other programming paradigm that your audience may not share.

Comment: I basically want to create an array of N empty arrays and push values (type double) in them.

Comment: If you are using the term `array` in the R sense, it is (perhaps) unfortunate, since R arrays must have a specific dimension at the time of creation. PLEASE ... do read what I have written so far and instead of clarifying in the comments ... edit your question so it has more specificity and clarity to an informed used of R who does not share whatever unstated assumptions you are making about notation.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do this:

`list_a<-vector("list",number_of_vectors)` 
and then set each list item using

`list_a[[i]]<-c(list_a[[i]],num_to_push_back);` etc for each `i`.

You can grow the vectors in the list - but it is not really advisable to grow things in `R`...

Then you can do `list_a[[a]][b]` for your array. But the syntax is tragic, and I bet the performance will be slower than Jackson on propofol.

Another, more "R-idiomatic" way to avoid the use of ragged arrays might be to pre-allocate (or create/whatever) a matrix with dimensions larger than the length of your largest vector. The missing values of shorter vectors could be populated with `NA` - many/most functionality in R is designed to cope with `NA`. Or simply use the function `na.omit` when using the vectors. For instance

```
Not_a_ragged_array=matrix(NA,10,10) #a 10 by 10 matrix filled with NAs
#fill each column with a vector of random numbers, of random length 
num_rows=sample.int(9,10,replace=TRUE); for(i in 1:10){Not_a_ragged_array[1:num_rows[i],i]=rbinom(num_rows[i],10,0.8)}
Not_a_ragged_array
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    8    9    7    8    7   10    8    7    9     9
# [2,]    8   10   NA    6    8    9    8   NA    8     6
# [3,]    7    7   NA   10    7    9    9   NA    9     9
# [4,]   NA    9   NA    6   10    7   NA   NA    6     9
# [5,]   NA    5   NA    9    7    6   NA   NA   NA     9
# [6,]   NA    8   NA    9    9   NA   NA   NA   NA     8
# [7,]   NA   NA   NA    9   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     9
# [8,]   NA   NA   NA    8   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA     8
# [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA
#[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA

as.vector(na.omit(Not_a_ragged_array[,1])) #get individual vectors like this
#[1] 8 8 7
```

Comment: This is the functionality I was looking for.  Not too familiar with R data types and performance- is there a more advisable way of accomplishing this?

Comment: That is OK. Generally people ask questions when they are not familiar with the answer...so its expected. I *think* this is the only (other methods are variations of this) way in R to create the object you are looking for (ragged array). You could look here for variations on same theme: http://www.r-bloggers.com/efficient-ragged-arrays-in-r-and-rcpp/ . To determine if your *actual* problem really requires the use of a ragged array, one would need to know more about your problem. I've edited the answer with a more "R idiomatic" suggestion to avoid ragged arrays.